# How does electronic speckle holography produce fringes?

Tags: optics, interferometry

For the out-of-plane set-up shown below, the system is only sensitive to displacements of the object along the z-axis.

[image]

To create an ESPI image, an image before an after displacing the test object are taken. An image of the difference between these images is then captured which produces a fringe pattern.

Why does this difference produce a fringe pattern?

I understand that displacing the test object along the z axis would shift the fringe pattern that a pair of points on the rough surface creates but I'm not entirely sure how to relate this to the fringe pattern of an ESPI image.